# Retrieving data by a MultiIndex

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that contains a multiindex.  I need to work with various subsets of the data based on schema and/or script (the indexes are `schema` and `script`).  The dataframe looks like this:

```
                          tx_id  step  step_id          start_time                                                     
schema_10 cmc_v2_file      19-3    10      279 2015-09-04 00:46:30   
          cmc_v2_file       2-7    10      423 2015-09-04 00:46:22   
          cmc_v2_file      29-1    10       20 2015-09-04 00:46:34   
          cmc_v2_file      35-1     4       63 2015-09-04 00:46:51   
          cmc_v2_file      31-2    10       79 2015-09-04 00:46:54   
          cmc_v2_file       5-8    10      536 2015-09-04 00:46:57   
          cmc_v2_file       5-9    10      610 2015-09-04 00:47:13   
          cmc_v2_file      39-1    10      178 2015-09-04 00:47:12   
          cmc_v2_file      41-1    10      211 2015-09-04 00:47:22   
          cmc_v2_file      21-4    10      678 2015-09-04 00:47:28   
          cmc_v2_file      23-4    10      698 2015-09-04 00:47:31   
          cmc_v2_file      31-5    10      399 2015-09-04 00:47:45   
          cmc_v2_file      35-4     3      453 2015-09-04 00:47:54   
          cmc_v2_file      29-5     4      461 2015-09-04 00:47:54   
          cmc_v2_file      29-5     8      465 2015-09-04 00:47:55   
          cmc_v2_file      42-3     1      467 2015-09-04 00:47:57   
          cmc_v2_file      22-5     8      866 2015-09-04 00:47:53   
          cmc_v2_file      16-6     8      893 2015-09-04 00:47:51   
          cmc_v2_file      17-6     4      938 2015-09-04 00:47:54   
          cmc_v2_file      17-6     8      942 2015-09-04 00:47:55   
          cmc_v2_file       6-2    10      707 2015-09-04 00:47:50   
          cmc_v2_file      4-11    10      730 2015-09-04 00:47:54   
          cmc_v2_file       6-3     2      745 2015-09-04 00:47:53   
          cmc_v2_file      5-11     1      762 2015-09-04 00:47:55   
          cmc_v2_file      4-12     1      763 2015-09-04 00:47:56   
          cmc_v2_file      5-12    10      782 2015-09-04 00:48:16   
          cmc_v2_file      31-6     4      471 2015-09-04 00:47:55   
          cmc_v2_file      38-3     4      520 2015-09-04 00:47:51   
          cmc_v2_file      39-3     4      551 2015-09-04 00:47:55   
          cmc_v2_file      31-7    10      570 2015-09-04 00:48:20   
...                         ...   ...      ...                 ...   
schema_9  hcs-vbu      1332-132    14   197542 2015-09-04 00:29:46   
          hcs-vbu       515-143     5   196309 2015-09-04 00:29:01   
          hcs-vbu       552-126    13   196333 2015-09-04 00:29:19   
          hcs-vbu       559-116    12   197068 2015-09-04 00:29:33   
          hcs-vbu       566-115    13   197201 2015-09-04 00:29:47   
          hcs-vbu       523-152     3   197443 2015-09-04 00:29:33   
          hcs-vbu       790-136     2   200774 2015-09-04 00:28:46   
          hcs-vbu       790-136     4   200776 2015-09-04 00:28:56   
          hcs-vbu       790-136    12   200784 2015-09-04 00:29:13   
          hcs-vbu       206-148     5   198213 2015-09-04 00:29:04
```

In order to get the data for a particular script I am doing this:

```
df.loc(axis=0)[:,[script]]
```

and when I print out the entire dataframe it looks correct.  The issue is that I am also writing a unit test for all of this and for part of the test I wanted to verify that the data contained only one script:

```
scripts = df.index.levels[df.index.names.index('script')]
```

However, instead of returning a list of one like I expected I get a list of 6 which is the number of scripts in the original unfiltered data.  Is there a different way I should be retrieving the script index once the data frame is filtered via a call to .loc?

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement `df.index.levels` gets all levels in your index. You then subset it by saying, give me all the levels in the second multiindex (called 'script').

What I think you want is something like this, where you say, for the index named 'script', give me a *particular* value.

```
## here we set a specific value you want to filter with

specific_script_value = cmc_v2_file

## and then we filter in the second dimension of the index. 
## The indexer helps slice in several dimensions

idx=pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:,specific_script_value],:]
```